# What do you absolutely have to know about a candidate before hiring him?

Tags: hiring

What **essential questions** do you have to know the answer for, about a prospective software development candidate, before hiring him/her?

I'm not seeking specific interview problems (e.g. sort this 3D array of numbers in O(1) complexity), but simply for things you need to find about, for yourself, about a new hire. (e.g. which source control systems / languages / frameworks / OS has he used?)

[Cross-posted to Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-do-you-absolutely-have-to-know-about-a-programmer-software-engineer-before-hiring-him)

Comment: I guessed this would be closed here. Sad. This is why the preemptive cross-post to Quora.

Comment: How is this (as stated) a problem unique to software development?

Comment: Why would you reject a candidate just because his previous project used a different source control system? Many times even a team lead can't pick the source control system, especially if they worked for a large company.

Comment: @ChrisF - it's implicit that the candidate is being hired for a programmer job. Do you think I should add this explicitly in the question?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - I never said anything about rejecting anyone. I still think it's a valid question, just to understand what the candidate brings to the table.

Comment: Yes, and you should make it clear you're asking for software development related skills. As it stands the question could apply to any profession. You're also asking a list question at the moment. These aren't a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ChrisF - Well, I'm never sure about Programmers SE, and how it stands about list questions. I always thought they "more acceptable here", but I guess that might not be the case. As it stands, with the swift downvotes (instead of edits) and closure, I don't see the reason to bother editing it myself simply to add "programmers". No offence, just practicality.

Comment: No problem. However, if you make significant edits (not just adding "programmer") then there's a chance that the question could be reopened. Closing is not the end of the line for a question.

Comment: P.S. I just wrote my own answer on Quora: http://www.quora.com/What-do-you-absolutely-have-to-know-about-a-programmer-software-engineer-before-hiring-him/answer/Ron-Gross

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm not sure how to edit the question in a way that would be on topic here. Do you have a suggestion? I know closing is not the end of the line ... but I sense a sentiment, and I don't know how to fix my question.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Talking about in [chat] might help. I'm not there though.

Comment: @ripper234 This may be of some interest to you: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-did-this-general-question-not-get-closed

Answer (score 4):

I would list the following areas which are a must before recruiting a candidate.

1. Attitude to learn: During the course of the interview, you can assess the candidates’ attitude to learn new things with case based analysis.
2. Passion for Programming: When the developer has passion for his work, his ability to bring out quality code is greater and he would be a great value edition once he adapts to your project.
3. Practical Knowledge: If the developer is experienced, they must have more practical knowledge in solving problems than theoretical knowledge.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you have to know if he has project experience in the field that you are hiring right now ; ) 
you also have to know if he is open to learning new things, and see that if he is excited about what you do. To understand this, you have to make him ask you about the stuff you are working on.

Comment: I'm aiming my questions at things that are knowable after an interview ... more like stuff you don't test for, but just ask or review his resume. It's good to know what his experience is and whether he's excited, but it's not always good to know for sure. Candidates often fake these. I'm looking for unfakeable hard facts - you either know git, or you don't, and it's usually easy to test for this.

Answer (score 1):

A degree is in my view quite unmistakeable. That shows that a candidate can finish something hard and persevere. In addition, you could give his references a ring, although they might be biased...